# Upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04lts to 18.04 can't be done because some existing packages are not being updated

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

When I run :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I get a message saying:

> Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

I have already run :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The final message here is :

> Some index files failed to download.  they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Towards the end of this output is the following:

> The following packages have been kept back:
> linux-generic  linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
> 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.

After this is when I ran :

```
sudo do-release-update
```

and that's when I get the message :

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
> Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

---

I saw this : [Can't upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS because can't upgrade libbluray-bdj](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117986/cant-upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-5-lts-to-18-04-1-lts-because-cant-upgrade-libbluray)

which seemed similar but unlike there the package was inconsequential here the packages seem central to the system.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Stop. Back up. Your output of `sudo apt update` indicates a problem ("*Some index files failed to download.*"). Don't move forward until you have solved that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
sudo apt install linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

to upgrade those forcefully.
I think after that `sudo do-release-update` will be accepted.

Comment: thank you very much.  This worked for me.